# passing dataframe and variables in function

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I am trying to pass dataframe and variable functions to plot some function
using plotnine in python. I am new to python. Is it possible to do so. My code is

```
def countPred_eda(dataset, variableName, targetVariable):
    print(dataset.variableName.describe())
    ggplot(dataset) + \
    aes(targetVariable, variableName, fill = targetVariable) + geom_boxplot(alpha = .8) + \
    labs(x =  targetVariable, y = variableName) + \
    ggtitle("Churn ratio with number_customer_service_calls ")
```

calling as

```
countPred_eda(train_data, number_customer_service_calls,churn)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assumed that `dataset` is of type pd.DataFrame and `variableName` and `targetVariable` are two strings which hold the names of two columns in this dataframe, you can do it like this with two exceptions:

1. Instead of `dataset.variableName.describe()` you have to use indexing syntax like `dataset[variableName].describe()`
2. The parameters of ggplot like e.g. `aes` belong inside the brackets directly behind `dataset`